# Sums of triangles

Tags: number-theory

If $P$ is any odd prime, is there a proof that working Mod P, each number from $0$ to $P-1$ except $\frac{(P^{2} -1)}{4}$ can be formed as the sum of the triangle of a number <(P+1)/2 and the triangle of a number < $\frac{(P-1)}{2}$ in the same number of different ways, and that if $P$ mod $4 \equiv  1$, $\frac{(P^{2} -1)}{4}$ can be formed in twice as many ways as the other numbers, and if $P$ mod $4 \equiv 3$, not at all?   I can only prove the last assertion.

Comment: What is "the triangle of a number"?